# Salesforce API insert adds special characters

Tags: javascript, php, salesforce, special-characters, html-escape-characters

I am using salesforce PHP toolkit in order to insert values of javascript functions (Just in order to document functions I am using, not for execution in salesforce) inside a custom object I have.

In my PHP function I am saving a string like:

```
(function(d,f){var b={src:(d.location.protocol=="https:"?"https:":"http:")...
```

after I insert this string using SF API, The result I see in the field is:

```
(function(d,f){var b={src:(d.location.protocol==&quot;https:&quot;?&quot;...
```

As you can see, salesforce has added special characters to my string. 
I haven't found anyway to pass that.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the htmlspecialchars from the string. I didn't think that SF would accept the string without because you could not echo the string without it as well (Due to special characters in my string). But it seems that it does pass the parameter without any issue. I'd be happy to understand that if anyone understands.